# How to get selected value of boostrap dropdown in angular?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, custom-controls

How can I get the selected value from below dropdown.?

```
<ul class="nav-drop-menu" id="ddlHotelSort">
    <li class="liselect" value="{{ssort.Sort}}" ng-repeat="ssort in vm.searchsort">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="SortClass" name="Sortclass" style="left:0px" value="{{ssort.Sort}}">{{ssort.Name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Below is image of dropdown opening.. 
How can I handle event and model value in angular application..?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="nav-drop-menu" id="ddlHotelSort">
    <li class="liselect" ng-click="getSelectedItem(ssort);" value="{{ssort.Sort}}" ng-repeat="ssort in vm.searchsort">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="SortClass" name="Sortclass" style="left:0px" value="{{ssort.Sort}}">{{ssort.Name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

controller function

```
$scope.getSelectedItem = function(item){
  console.log(item);//selected item
}
```

Comment: another query, how to set focus on input control , also required validation with angular?

Answer (score 1):

Just call a function in the `li` click, here is an example with your options.

Just click on each li,

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[])

app.controller('MyCtrl',MyCtrl)

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.opts = ["Recommended","FirstClass","SecondClass","ThirdClass"            ];
    
    $scope.my_method = function(opt)
    {
    alert(opt)
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat=" opt in opts" ng-click="my_method(opt)">
        {{ opt }}
    </li>
    </ul>
    
    <p>{{opt}}</p>
</div>
```

**Run the code snippet and click on each `li`**

[HEre is an example fiddle with your options](http://jsfiddle.net/gFFBa/915/)